# JSF Message on SUBMIT action

Tags: jsf-2

I begin with my case:

JSF 2.1

Tomcat 7.0.27

Netbeans as IDE

JSF and PRIMEFace (but optional)

Level JSF beginner

Level JAVA good and not god

---

I have done a simple JSF site to learn how to works with JSF. My question is based on Login example at this step the problem is not related about that login that is obviously insicure.

A bit of code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
//@RequestScoped
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String userName = "User";
private final String userPassword = "12345";
private String name;
private String password;
private boolean isLogged=false;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}


public void setPassword( String password ) {
    this.password = password;
}


public String login() {
    if( !(userName==null || password==null)
        &&
        (userName.equals( name ) && userPassword.equals( password ))) {

        isLogged=false;
        return "main";
    } else {
        isLogged=true;
        return "index";
    }



}

public boolean getIsLogged(){
    return isLogged;
}
}
```

The page index

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>TSAM 7.5 Login</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            Login system
            <br />
            <!--<h:link outcome="welcomePrimefaces" value="Primefaces welcome page" />-->
            <h:form>
                User : <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" />
                Password : <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}" />
                <h:commandButton action="#{user.login()}" value="Submit" />
                <h:commandButton value="reset" type="reset" />
                <h:commandButton value="otherpage" action="otherpage"></h:commandButton>

            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

The main page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{user.isLogged}"/> 
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>PrimeFaces</title>
            </f:facet>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>


            <p:layout fullPage="true">

                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Header
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Footer
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true">
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="Resources">
                            <p:menuitem value="Demo" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Documentation" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Forum" url="http://forum.primefaces.org/" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Themes" url="http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html" />

                        </p:submenu>

                    </p:menu>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    Welcome to PrimeFaces
                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>

        </h:body>

    </f:view>
</html>
```

First

I use action="#{user.login()}" to make navigation action is this correct or there is a better pattern?

But the real question is: How to show a message If I redirect?

I like to show a message I know the example by PrimeFace http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf. but it doesn't redirect or show anything.
But if i use only "plain" JSW without PrimeFace, i like to put a   
because it is similar to PrimeFaces so switch is simple.

I'd like to adopt a "pattern" so i can reuse it for eg when i do a serch an no data is present, or when i call "erease DB" and application say work in progress an then say OK all bank account are esreased (Only an example!! but interesting because there are 2 message).

Thanks

---

I try

```
public String login() {
        if (!(userName == null || password == null)
            && (userName.equals( name ) && userPassword.equals( password ))) {

            isLogged = true;
            return "main";
        } else {
            isLogged = false;
            FacesMessage facesMsg;
            facesMsg = new FacesMessage( FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "No login", "No login because username or passsword are incorrect etc" );
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            fc.addMessage( "loginError", facesMsg );
            return "index";
        }



    }
```

And edited the page

```
<h:body>
        Login system
        <br />
        <!--<h:link outcome="welcomePrimefaces" value="Primefaces welcome page" />-->
        <h:form>
            User : <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" />
            Password : <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}" />
            <h:commandButton action="#{user.login()}" value="Submit" />
            <h:commandButton value="reset" type="reset" />
            <h:commandButton value="Cambio Password" action="changePassword"></h:commandButton>


        </h:form>

        <h:message for="" style="color:red;margin:8px;"/>
    </h:body>
```

It works but it's not ok because it's not ok to put a string in the bean. And I need the multilanguage this string has to generated by the beans.... mmm this is not OK something i'm missing.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `FacesMessage` as in the example you mention?

Comment: @SJuan76 yes i have done i'm going to modify the question.

Comment: And the target page has the `h:messages` component?

Comment: Well he need a javascript function to be called only when there is no error messages from validation. I think this could be done adding f:ajax with the login button but I don't know too well f:ajax, I use the RichFaces equivalent a4j:ajax. The javascript function will show his redirection message! FacesMessage are discarded after page forward.

Comment: @SJuan76 in the bean you are redirected to index if login fail or to main if login succesful. When i return to index (login fail) i like to show why i have done nothing i like to show a message a popup or something that tells why the user is in login page. The second important thing is that Show a message from bean is not so correct because the bean has to manage the language that jsf il using, i prefer that bean telll something and JSF page show the message otherwise localization will be painful

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie  ok f:ajax cold be the solution, but only if there is anything better in JSF. Anyway i take a look for you suggestion

Comment: Note that you can mix FaceMessage and output in AJAX I think! So you'll keep your i18n from bean side.

Answer (score 0):

There's extremely a lot of noise in the question. I understand that your question ultimately boils down to:

> *How do I create a localized faces message in bean action method?*

In that case, just get the message from the current resource bundle yourself.

As you're talking about localization, you should surely already have something like as

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>com.example.i18n.text</base-name>
    <var>text</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

in your `faces-config.xml`. You could just get it in the bean as well with help of [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) which JSF itself is actually also using under the covers

```
Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
ResourceBundle text = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.i18n.text", locale);
```

This way you could compose your message as

```
String summary = text.getString("messages.no_login_summary");
String detail = text.getString("messages.no_login_detail");
new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, summary, detail);
```

Comment: Thanks i18n is the first thing that demotivate people that could answer to write directly a string, There are a lot of solution but i think that a good one should consider important things. I'm absolutely newbie in JSF but not in programming or JAVA, I usually separate the GUI and backend. I'm doing a simple examplet to learn something, so i have the first problem show someting as the result of action... so you think that FacesMessage is the correct way to show that type of information? All example about FacesMessage mix JSF and Bean, so i ask show information setted directly by a Bean is OK?